# How do I enable the Docker RestAPI on Windows Containers?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I used [this official guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_server) to install Docker Containers on Windows. Everything looks good and I can run IIS on Windows Containers now.

However, I don't see it anywhere and have no idea on how to "Enable Rest API" for it. How can I do this?

Comment: Please post your solution in the answer section below, rather than as an update to your question. Thanks, and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Finally, I found how to enable Remote API of Docker Containers on Windows. The key point is file *daemon.json* which place in *C:\ProgramData\docker\config*.

In the guide linked in the question, the author only mention that we should place in it something like:

```
{"hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2376", "npipe://"]}
```

But when I try to add this to *daemon.json*, my daemon don't work on CLI. At last, I reverse the order of array like

```
{"hosts": ["npipe://", "tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"]}
```

My docker will work well in both CLI & Remote API. Good experience with Windows Docker and thanks for your attention!

Comment: So assuming above port and localhost as ip after doing all those steps I could connect via the Docker.Dotnet NuuGet package? Like this: `DockerClient client = new DockerClientConfiguration(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:2376"))
     .CreateClient();` Would that be right? Link to library: https://github.com/Microsoft/Docker.DotNet

Comment: I'm not the author of this material @SvenM., I just extracted it out of a question edit and created this answer. If you comment under the question, the OP may well see it and reply to you. However, perhaps this merits a fresh question, if it is at all different to the above? It's not my area, so I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Just came across the same issue, and discovered the REST API was already enabled!

### TLDR;

```sh
set API=https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.24/containers/json?all=1
set CERT=C:\Users\Nick\.docker\machine\machines\default
curl --cert "%CERT%/cert.pem" --cacert "%CERT%/ca.pem" --key "%CERT%/key.pem" "%API%"
```

---

Here's how I accessed the REST API from the windows `cmd`.

1. Check docker version
2. Check the URL of the machine I want to connect to (`default` > `192.168.99.100:2376`)
3. Set an Environment Variable to the location of the certificates
4. Perform a CURL request on the REST endpoint (`/v1.24/containers/json?all=1`)

#### i.e.

```sh
C:\Users\Nick>docker --version
Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302

C:\Users\Nick>docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v18.03.0-ce

C:\Users\Nick>set DOCKER_CA=C:\Users\Nick\.docker\machine\machines\default

C:\Users\Nick>curl --cert "%DOCKER_CA%/cert.pem" --cacert "%DOCKER_CA%/ca.pem" --key "%DOCKER_CA%/key.pem" https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.24/containers/json?all=1
[]
```

For those that are interested...

- **Docker REST API** - https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/