# Docker Rest API to Perform Docker Operations Remotely

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I want to connect to a Windows Server Where Docker is Running (Windows Server 2016) and do all the docker operations programmatically using Rest Calls. Can Anyone provide me the Docker Rest API to connect to Windows Server and perform those operations like Docker Container Creation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable the Docker RestAPI on Windows Containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854161/how-do-i-enable-the-docker-restapi-on-windows-containers)

Comment: Just remember that doing this has massive security implications: on Linux, anyone who can reach the socket has unrestricted administrator access on the host and can edit any file on the system and do anything.  I think it's slightly more controlled on MacOS/Windows but it's still not something I'd do casually (or at all).

Answer (score 0):

Check docker engine api. It gives you some REST endpoints like, `GET /containers/json` to list all containers.

If you are looking for programmatically doing REST API calls in C#, you can look into [Docker.DotNet](https://github.com/Microsoft/Docker.DotNet).

You can use Git Bash for Windows to query something like

```
curl http://localhost:2375/containers/<your_conatiner_name>/stats
```

Or, if you want to remotely request docker demon then follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37178824/3925626)